# How to extract the key and values from a dictionary which is present inside the List in python? eg: list1 = ["john", 10, 20, {"joe":50, "robert";60}]

Tags: python

How to extract the key and values from a dictionary which is present inside the List in python?

eg:

```
list1 = ["john", 10, 20, {"joe":50, "robert";60}]
```

How to make a new list with the values of the dictionary from the above list?

Comment: Welcome to SO! First research for steps to solve your problem: (1) [extract element from list](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[python]+extract%20element%20form%20list), to extract the dictionary, then (2) [get values from dict](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+get+values+from+dict), then you can (3) [create a new list](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+create+a+list+from+values) from those values - research is required, see [ask]. After your research, write code and try it, e.g. in Python shell REPL. If your code does not work, present it here as [example].

Answer (score 1):

#### Locate the dictionary - know its index in given list

If you want to create a list of the values of the dictionary mentioned, you need to get the dictionary first.  This can be done if you know where the dictionary is - the example you provided - or if you need to find it using [sigmapie8's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75673354/5730279).

#### Extract dictionary, get its values into new list

Assume we know that the wanted dictionary is the 4th element in given list, we can access it with zero-based index as `list1[3]`.

Once you have the dictionary you need to get its values with [`values()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.values) and put them into a new list.

This can be done on one line. I will use your provided example to show my point.

```py
list1 = ["john", 10, 20, {"joe":50, "robert":60}]

new_list = list(list1[3].values())
```

You can then `print()` the *new_list*. Expected output:

```
[50,60]
```

I believe this is what you are looking to do. Again this can be combined with the previously mentioned answers if you do not know where your dictionary is located within the original list.

Comment: Doesn't `list1[3].values()` already give the expected list? Why do we need to wrap it using `list()` before assigning?

Comment: @hc_dev the output of printing list1[3].values() is a view object: ```dict_values([50,60])```.  Wrapping this view object in a call to  ```list()``` gives us a list that looks more like what one expects from a list and also has the proper type of list.

Answer (score 0):

#### Function to extract dictionary values and keys from a list

```py
def dictionary_unpaker(list_with_dict):
    """
    This function extracts a dictionary in given list and returns items of the dictionary as tuple (values, keys).
    If the given list contains no dictionary, an error message as string will be returned.
    """
    key_list=[]
    value_list=[]
    for i in list_with_dict:
        dictionary={}
        if type(i)==dict:
            dictionary=i
            break
    else :
         return "There isn't any dictionary in your list"      
    for key,value in dictionary.items():
        key_list.append(key)
        value_list.append(value)
    return value_list,key_list
```

Note: It will only extract the first dictionary found.

#### Example usage

Given your list, the function can be used like this:

```
list1 = ["john", 10, 20, {"joe":50, "robert":60}]
tuple = dictionary_unpaker(list1)
print(tuple)
# ([50, 60], ['joe', 'robert'])
values = tuple[0]  # to get only the values index the first element
```

Comment: Please improve code-formatting to include the function head with proper indentation. Improve doc-string to clarify what happens when list does not contain dicts at all, or more than one. `list` is a keyword and discouraged as name.. `dictionary` is well-named avoiding keyword `dict`

Answer (score -1):

```py
list1 = ["john", 10, 20, {"joe":50, "robert":60}]

for item in list1:
  if(isinstance(item, dict)):
    print(item)
    # do whatever you want with it
```

Comment: `type(item) == dict` also works

Comment: @MoRe Even that is frowned upon. Use `isinstance(item, dict)`!

Comment: @user2390182 I used same way in my answer... I just want to show `str` is useless here

Comment: Thanks, I'll change my answer accordingly